Cordova iOS application - Opening a barcode reader causes a new screen to appear on top of the existing screen
After a recent IOS update, when we open the scanner an additional blank screen pops out apart from the regular scanner screen because of which the scanner functionality doesn't work. Refer attached video
Package used: vue-barcode-reader (https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-barcode-reader)
Created iOS build in Quasar
<template>
  <q-page class="pages q-pa-none">
    <div class="flex full-width justify-center items-center">
      <div class="neumorphism q-ma-md q-pa-md">
        <q-spinner
          color="primary"
          size="3em"
          :thickness="4"
          v-if="!scanerLoaded"
        />
        <StreamBarcodeReader
          @decode="onDecode"
          @loaded="onLoaded"
        ></StreamBarcodeReader>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="barcodePwaInfo neumorphism q-pa-lg">
      {{ result }}
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { StreamBarcodeReader } from "vue-barcode-reader";

const scanedInProgress = ref(false);
const scanerLoaded = ref(false);
const result = ref("");

function onDecode(text) {
  result.value = text;
}
function onLoaded() {
  scanedInProgress.value = false;
  scanerLoaded.value = true;
}

function scanned(result) {
  console.log(result);
}
</script>

Here is the video for the issues (https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-barcode-reader/assets/94589861/a2c7401f-0401-44ab-b3b4-c642f7aafd50)
I have try multiple way but didn't work.

Very confusing as to what is not working. Also, do you need a mobile app to read a QR code, can't it be a web app?

I used vue-barcode-reader package for my hybrid application using the Quasar framework. When I open a page that implements this package that time new screen appears in black. This happens only on iOS devices and works well in android applications. You can see this in the attached video.

Not sure but I see the actual scanner appearing at some point. Not sure if authorization might be needed? But the video looks like it is working.

The scanner is working fine but at the same time when I visit that page first, this black screen appears.

So everything works fine but it's a bit slow? Maybe the time it takes to initialize?

let me share another video.

@kissu Please check the video URL I have uploaded a new video. https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-barcode-reader/assets/94589861/a2c7401f-0401-44ab-b3b4-c642f7aafd50

@kissu if you did not understand the question please ask. Without understanding the concern or question, don't vote down any user. If you are interested in solving the problem then understand the question and give the solution.

Upvotes/downvotes here are anonymous and subject to people's appreciation given the lack of context etc, nothing else people follow this website's rules. Regarding your issue, if you're sure that it's after an iOS update, I recommend that you read the changelogs of that specific update from a technical point to narrow down where the issue might come from. Otherwise, as you did: you can always ask about the given project as you did with context because it is always important whatever the platform. After reading a few issues, people have a lot of issue with that specific package, try another one

@kissu We attempted two distinct packages, but the problem persists. iOS is experiencing similar problems.

Then you narrowed it down to iOS, check the logs/forums. Try to confirm it by using an older iOS version.

I encountered a similar issue after a recent iOS update, where opening the scanner would trigger an additional blank screen, rendering the scanner functionality inoperative. After three days of extensive research and development, I experimented with several approaches and finally discovered a solution.
To resolve the issue, add the following line to your config.xml file:
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />

This setting allows inline media playback, which seems to mitigate the problem caused by the iOS update. Inline media playback is essential for certain functionalities in Cordova applications, particularly those involving camera or media elements. By enabling this preference, the scanner screen operates correctly without displaying the additional blank screen.
Here is the updated section of config.xml for reference:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="your.app.id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>YourAppName</name>
    <description>Your app description</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">Your Name</author>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <!-- other configurations -->
</widget>

This solution worked for my setup, which includes vue-barcode-reader, Quasar, Cordova, and Vue 3. If you're facing similar issues, I recommend trying this configuration change.
